# Setting umask for su root

Tags: su, umask

In my user account I set the `umask` to be `022` with my `.bashrc`, but I want root to use a `umask` of `077` no matter how I become root (e.g., logging in directly as root on a tty or using sudo or su). If I login to a tty as root, I get `077`, so it is fine. For `sudo` in `/etc/sudoers` I have set

```
Defaults umask = 0022
Defaults umask_override
```

and I get `077`, so again fine. For `su`, in /root/.bashrc I can set

```
umask 022
```

and I get a `umask` of `077`, but I am not convinced this is the correct way to do it.

How do you set the `umask` for `su root`

Potentially relevant is that my `/etc/login.defs` has

```
UMASK           077
USERGROUPS_ENAB yes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is bash specific, other shells have similar features, but since your answer mentioned `.bashrc` I'm going to assume you're using Bash.

What you're encountering is that a shell can either be invoked as an interactive or a login shell.

- `bash -l` - login
- `bash -i` - interactive

If you look in the Bash man page in the "INVOCATION" section you'll notice the following 2 comments:

- login

  > A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option.
- interactive

  > An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments and
  >   without the -c option whose standard input and error  are  both  connected to
  >   terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.
  >   PS1 is set and $- includes i if bash is interactive, allowing a shell script 
  >   or a startup file to test this state.

Interactive & login shells read the config files in the following order. It does this one first:

1. /etc/profile

Followed by one of these (which ever it finds first) in this order:

1. ~/.bash_profile
2. ~/.bash_login
3. ~/.profile

Interactive shells (that are not a login shell) read an additional config file, `~/.bashrc`. Notice that they never read the `/etc/bashrc` config file directly. They read it through the `~/.bashrc` file because of this stanza:

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

#### So what about the umask

To get both types of shells to read the `umask` you need to include it in one of the files mentioned above that both types of shell invocations will read, so I'd put it in `/root/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set root's umask in `/root/.profile` and tell `su` to start the shell as a login shell.

```
su -
```